# Find absolute name in file by grep

Tags: linux, grep

I use the command :

```
grep "pdp" /3.log
```

for searching lines containing `pdp` details. But I got also lines with `fpdp`, `spdp` ..

How could I filter only the relevant name that i choose ?

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your log by editing your question

Comment: On what criteria would you want to exclude `fpdp`? Would you also want to exclude `f pdp`, `f-pdp`, `f_pdp`, `Fpdp`, `f/pdp`? Is it because `pdp` is preceded by a letter in `fpdp` or because it's preceded by anything other than whitespace or a slash?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you want:

```
grep -w pdp /3.log
```

From the [manpage of the GNU implementation of `grep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

> -w, --word-regexp
>                 Select only those lines containing matches that form whole
>                 words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be
>                 at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word
>                 constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the
>                 end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent
>                 character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits,
>                 and the underscore.  This option has no effect if -x is also
>                 specified.

Comment: great, thanks
grep -w    -- is what i ask for

Comment: @shaul You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).

Answer (score 0):

As mention by JRFerguson you can use grep -w pdp to get only matching results or you can use find:

```
[root@testvm ~]# ls -lrth
total 4.0K
-rw-------. 1 root root 1.4K Mar 16 13:39 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 May 19 18:11 pdp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 May 19 18:11 pdpabc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 May 19 18:11 abcpdp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 May 19 18:11 3pdp
[root@testvm ~]# find . -regex "\./pdp"
./pdp
```

it may be usefulto use find if you are willing to move those matching content or delete:

```
find . -regex "\./pdp" -exec mv /tmp \;
```

Comment: They are trying to find the string in a file, not as part of a filename.